# How can I optimize the code to make one df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some `CSV` files. These files consist of some rows and columns. First, I filtered the file (after reading based on 2 conditions) and then calculate the `correlation` using `df.corr()`.

```
result_df = pd.read_csv("/home/output_1.csv")
met_1_lr = result_df.loc[(result_df.Regressor == "LinReg") & (result_df.Method == "method_1")]
print((met_1_lr.corr().round(2).constant))

met_2_lr = result_df.loc[(result_df.Regressor == "LinReg") & (result_df.Method == "method_2")]
print(met_2_lr.corr().round(2).constant)
```

The CSV file contains 5 different `Regressor` and 5 different `Method`. So, I have to write (actually repeat the same code after changing the conditions) 5 * 5 = 25 times (only for 1 CSV file) to get the output.

How can I optimize the code, so that, I do not have to repeat and can get only one `df` for all output? Something like the below one

```
file_name   regressor   method  rest_of_the_output(correlation output multiples columns)

file_1  LinReg  met_1   corr_output(more multiples columns)
file_1  LinReg  met_2   corr_output(more multiples columns)
file_1  Knn  met_1   corr_output(more multiples columns)
file_1  Knn  met_2   corr_output(more multiples columns)
file_2  LinReg  met_1   corr_output(more multiples columns)
file_2  LinReg  met_2   corr_output(more multiples columns)
file_2  Knn  met_1   corr_output(more multiples columns)
file_2  Knn  met_2   corr_output(more multiples columns)
```

Comment: I guess you need `groupby` -> `result_df.groupby(['Regressor', 'Method'], as_index =False).apply(lambda x: x.corr().round(2).constant)`. Can you add a sample dataframe? you can use:  df.to_dict()

Comment: @Nk03 thanks. That works for one file. If I want to run the same code in multiple files and want to save the `file_name` then what I have to do?

Comment: I've added an answer!!. Still, I'm not that sure if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
csv_file_list = ['add csv files in this list']
final_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csv_file).groupby(['Regressor', 'Method'], as_index=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.corr().round(2).constant).assign(file_name=csv_file) for csv_file in csv_file_list])
```

Here, the idea is:

1. Iterate over multiple csv_files.
2. Use groupby apply to evaluate the correlation.
3. Then, add the new column `file_name`.
4. Finally concat the dataframes.

Comment: I am getting `Regressor` and `Method` 2 times (means 2 columns for `Regressor` and 2 columns for `Method`). Could you tell me why I am getting a reputation? The rest of the part is fine.

Comment: Can you try once without `as_index=False`  in groupby?? It's probably because of that. Else, you can try -> `.apply(
    lambda x: x.corr().round(2).constant).reset_index(drop =True)` see `reset_index()` after `groupby -apply`

Comment: Perfect (just removed `as_index=False`), thanks.